# Sideload a downgrade

Tags: 7.0-nougat, downgrade, side-loading

I side loaded 7.1.1 from 6.0, on my 2014 Nexus 6. I would like to downgrade to 7.0 (because of issues such as speakerphone echo). Can this be done via side loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this flawlessly with the [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/). I'm unsure how to do it on a Mac, though.